# Glass Mirror API save attatchment image to server via PHP

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am using the PHP quick start project example to display the timeline's attachment (image):

```
<?php
if ($timeline_item->getAttachments() != null) {
  $attachments = $timeline_item->getAttachments();
  foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $base_url .
          '/attachment-proxy.php?timeline_item_id=' .
          $timeline_item->getId() . '&attachment_id=' .
          $attachment->getId() ?>" />
  <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Now I need to save the image to the server so I can resize it and use it elsewhere. 
I have tried a few variations of file_put_contents, fopen, and curl but it seems attachment-proxy.php is not returning the image in a format that any of these expect.

How can save a Timeline Attachment to my server?

SOLUTION: Based on Prisoner's response I took another look at the attachment-proxy.php file. It is returning the image as a string. I had unsuccessfully tried file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents("attachment-proxy.php....")); before.
Turns out I don't need the file_get_contents() part. 
I altered the last few lines of attachment-proxy.php to this:

```
$img = $_GET['timeline_item_id'].'.jpg';
$image = download_attachment($_GET['timeline_item_id'], $attachment);
file_put_contents($img, $image);
```

It works. It saves the image to my server with the ID as the file name. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see what it **is** returning? The attachment_proxy.php requires OAuth to have been completed, and will redirect you through the OAuth flow if this hasn't been done. So it may very well be that it is saving the HTML for the OAuth login page, or the information from the redirect page.

However, if you're trying to setup something on your server that calls your own server's attachment_proxy.php page... you're jumping through additional unnecessary hoops.

You can probably take a look directly at attachment_proxy.php to see how it is getting the attachment data from Google's servers, and then use this same method to get them and store them on your server instead of just feeding it out for the img tag. Looking at https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php/blob/master/attachment-proxy.php it seems like most of the work is done in a call to `download_attachments()` which is located in https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php/blob/master/mirror-client.php. You should be able to either borrow the code from `download_attachments()` or call it directly yourself.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. I will add my solution to the question.